# NPE у GridView Adapter`a и немного Магии(!!!)

Tags: android

Вопрос скорее всего очень детский и глупый, но я ломаю голову уже несколько дней, поэтому прошу дочитать до конца. Уже всё перепробовал, возможно ошибка кроется в самых основах, которые я весьма небрежно изучил и сразу перешёл к кодингу.

В своём приложении использую YouTube API, который требует YOUTUBE_API_KEY и подписанный сертификат. После подписания появилась необходимость немного изменить приложение.

Есть MainActivity с двумя кнопками, которые ведут на Activity1 и Activity2. В Activity1 как раз используется YOUTUBE_API_KEY, GridView адаптер и т.д. Здесь всё работает правильно.

Activity2 тоже работает правильно, здесь есть адаптер для разметки GridView. Но как только я меняю layout(допустим добавляю кнопку Button) у Activity2, Activity1 перестаёт работать(WTF?!?), а именно вылетает NPE. Лэйауты у этих активити разные и никак не связаны, поэтому я немного ошарашен, как такое может быть.

Вот код, где я инициализирую адаптер и на какую строчку ссылается лог:

```
 GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewVideo);
    gridview.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this));
```

Вот лог ошибки:

> 09-25 09:10:13.322 15921-15921/com422studio.vk.drawinglessons
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com422studio.vk.drawinglessons, PID: 15921
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com422studio.vk.drawinglessons/com422studio.vk.drawinglessons.VideoChoose}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                                                                                    **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com422studio.vk.drawinglessons.VideoChoose.onCreate(VideoChoose.java:39)**
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

```
public class VideoChoose extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_choose_layout);

        initToolbar();

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewVideo);
        gridview.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this));


        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(VideoChoose.this, VideoGallery.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initToolbar(){

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Видео уроки");

        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_icon));
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(VideoChoose.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> video_choose_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <GridView

        android:id="@+id/gridViewVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

> Activity2:

```
public class ActivityGallery extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery_layout);

        initToolbar();

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewImage);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mThumbIds));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(gridviewOnItemClickListener);

    }

    private GridView.OnItemClickListener gridviewOnItemClickListener = new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    FullActivityGallery.class);

            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    };

    private void initToolbar(){

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Галерея");   
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_icon));
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityGallery.this, MainActivity.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
        });
    }
}
```

> gallery_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: скорее всего, дело в невнимательности, и вы пропустили какую-то мелочь. Придется выложить код `VideoChoose` и разметку xml, которую использует `VideoChoose`

Comment: Да, и если вы используете Instant Run - отключите его ко всем чертям. Он кривой, глючит и не работает.

Comment: @metalurgus да я понимаю, что проблема где-то в невнимательности, но я никак не могу найти где я ошибся. Код я добавил.Подскажите в каком направлении копать

Comment: а второй layout и activity где ? fill_parent?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Добавил, правда уж слишком уж большая стена кода получилась..

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei изменил где возможно fill_parent на match_parent и ошибка перестала вылетать (лол?) С чем это связано?